# avoid kex_exchange_identification error in git

Tags: linux, bash, git, github

I write a script in linux that run **git pull origin master** for multi folder,
in 5th folder its return error :

> kex_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
> fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

ther is my script :

```
#!/bin/bash

FOLDERS[0]="alpha"
FOLDERS[1]="beta"
FOLDERS[2]="gamma"
FOLDERS[3]="landa"
FOLDERS[4]="sigma"
FOLDERS[5]="delta"
FOLDERS[6]="etta"


cd /
for item in "${FOLDERS[@]}"
do
   echo "working on $item please wait ... "
   cd /home/$item/
   git pull origin master

   echo "successfully pulled $item  "

done
```

The problem is that using multiple concurrent ssh connections to Bitbucket GitHub from the same IP address — you are flagged as a possible DDoS and thus GitHub throws you with the Connection reset by peer.

**how can I avoid this problem?  I do not want to use http inested of ssh connection**

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid concurrent connections, you can add `sleep` command. Your script will be work longer, but it should be works without errors.

Try to add: `sleep 30` after the line: `git pull origin master`.